# C# Set translatetransform X and Y property relative to MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Wrappanel hosted inside ItemsControl which is wrapped in a scrollviewer. Items in a wrappanel are populated with binding. Every item has a datatemplate with a datatrigger. That trigger is suposed to animate the item to the center of the screen. I was trying to do that with translatetransform, but the problem is that X and Y properties of translatetransform is relative to the item itself and not the host container, so every item has a different animation. As seen here:

[webm 1](http://webmshare.com/play/jj39d)
[webm 2](http://webmshare.com/play/dLj97)

The item template XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CountryItemTemplate">
    <Grid 
        x:Name="gridMain"
        Height="Auto"
        Width="Auto"
        Margin="3"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0 0"
        Panel.ZIndex="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <materialDesign:Card 
            x:Name="cardMain" 
            Height="350" 
            Width="310"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
            materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1"
            UniformCornerRadius="3">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle
                    Grid.Row="0">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    FontWeight="Regular"
                    FontSize="25"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="16 24 0 0"
                    Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
                    Content="Edit"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Width="85"
                    Height="35"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="0 0 16 24"
                    Command="{Binding IsInEditModeToggleCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
            <materialDesign:Card.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </materialDesign:Card.RenderTransform>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInEditMode, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="cardMain"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).Children[1].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                            To="300"
                            By="1"
                            Duration="0:0:2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <ExponentialEase
                                    EasingMode="EaseInOut"
                                    Exponent="16"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="cardMain"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).Children[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                            To="400"
                            By="1"
                            Duration="0:0:2">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <ExponentialEase
                                    EasingMode="EaseInOut"
                                    Exponent="16"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

I tried to use UIElement.TranslatePoint like this :

The whole UserControl where everything is:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.Views.CountryUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.DomainModels"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.Helpers"
    xmlns:mahApps="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.Helpers.ValidationRules"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.Views"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NikolaLukovic.CustomsOfficeApp.Desktop.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="600" 
    d:DesignWidth="900">
    <UserControl.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache/>
    </UserControl.CacheMode>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=icMain}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:CountryViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/CountryItemStyle.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Icons.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/MaterialDesignIcons.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Shadows.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ToggleButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <materialDesign:DialogHost>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    x:Name="icMain"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountryItemTemplate}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Countries, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Button
                Width="45"
                Height="45"
                Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}" 
                Grid.Column="1" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0 10 0 0">
                <Viewbox Width="24" Height="24">
                    <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                        <Path Data="M19,13H13V19H11V13H5V11H11V5H13V11H19V13Z" Fill="White" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
</UserControl>
```

The DataContext ViewModel:

```
public class CountryViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CountryItem> countries;
        private DelegateCommand<ItemsControl> loadDataCommand;

        public CountryViewModel ( )
        {
            ViewModelFinder.Add(this);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CountryItem> Countries
        {
            get
            {
                return countries;
            }

            set
            {
                this.countries = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DelegateCommand<ItemsControl> LoadDataCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if ( this.loadDataCommand == null )
                    this.loadDataCommand = new DelegateCommand<ItemsControl>(async icMain => await LoadDataMethod(icMain));

                return this.loadDataCommand;
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadDataMethod (ItemsControl icMain)
        {
            if ( this.Countries == null )
            {
                var countries = await CountryService.Instance.GetAllAsync();
                this.Countries = new ObservableCollection<CountryItem>();
                var util = new Util();
                foreach ( var country in countries.Take(40) )
                {
                    var countryItem = new CountryItem
                    {
                        Name = country.Name,
                        Iso2 = country.Iso2,
                        IsoAlpha3 = country.IsoAlpha3,
                        IsoUnM49Numerical = country.IsoUnM49Numerical,
                        Id = country.Id
                    };
                    var imageBytes = await util.GetImageBytesAsync(country.CountryFlagUrl);
                    countryItem.ImageUrl = country.CountryFlagUrl;
                    this.Countries.Add(countryItem);
                    countryItem.This = icMain.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(countryItem) as UIElement;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Class that represents the item in a wrappanel:

```
public class CountryItem : ObservableObject
    {
        private bool isEnabled = true;
        private bool isInEditMode;
        private bool isVisible = true;
        private DelegateCommand isInEditModeToggleCommand;
        private string name;
        private string iso2;
        private string isoAlpha3;
        private int isoUnM49Numerical;
        private string imageUrl;
        private Guid id;
        private UIElement @this;

        public CountryItem ( )
        {

        }

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return isEnabled;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isEnabled = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Iso2 is required.")]
        public string Iso2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.iso2;
            }
            set
            {
                this.iso2 = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Iso Alpha3 is required.")]
        public string IsoAlpha3
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isoAlpha3;
            }
            set
            {
                this.isoAlpha3 = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Iso Un M49 Numerical is required.")]
        public int IsoUnM49Numerical
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isoUnM49Numerical;
            }
            set
            {
                this.isoUnM49Numerical = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return imageUrl;
            }

            set
            {
                this.imageUrl = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Guid Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                this.id = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsInEditMode
        {
            get
            {
                return isInEditMode;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isInEditMode = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DelegateCommand IsInEditModeToggleCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if ( this.isInEditModeToggleCommand == null )
                    this.isInEditModeToggleCommand = new DelegateCommand(IsInEditModeToggleMethod);

                return this.isInEditModeToggleCommand;
            }
        }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return isVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isVisible = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public UIElement This
        {
            get
            {
                return this.@this;
            }

            set
            {
                this.@this = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void IsInEditModeToggleMethod ( )
        {
            var countryViewModel = ViewModelFinder.FindOne<CountryViewModel>();
            countryViewModel.Countries.Where(x=>x.Id != this.Id).ToList().ForEach(ci => ci.IsVisible = false);
            this.This.TranslatePoint(new Point(400, 500), Application.Current.MainWindow)
            this.IsInEditMode = !this.IsInEditMode;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate coordinates with [`UIElement.TranslatePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. Then you just need a way to use the translated value in your animation, there should be multiple ways to accomplish this.

One option would be, to have a dedicated `CurrentEditItem` outside the collection and modify the window content template based on, whether this property is set. This way, the relation between window and item should be easier to model. But I'm sure its also possible to just throw a binding and converter on your `To` values, in order to have them translate window-to-item coordinate values.

For example, a converter that is instantiated as a static resource on your window with a reference to the window and a `ConverterParameter` with your item would allow you, to convert any incomming value between window and item coordinates.

Comment: i did try that, when i create items for the collection i also make a reference to the UIElement created for the specific item, and in a command try to use translatepoint. The reference uielement i use for that method is the MainWindow, which i get from Application.Current.MainWindow. But when i do that, nothing happens, the item doesn't move at all.

Comment: I've also tried referencing the host UserControl, and adding it's reference to every item so i can try to TranslatePoint using that user control but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic First thing first... `TranslatePoint` has no effect on the caller but returns a transformed coordinate. So in your `IsInEditModeToggleMethod`, you have to assign the result of `TranslatePoint` to something.

Comment: yeah, that's right, i just solved the problem, i'll post an answer soon. thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to ditch the storyboard animation from xaml and do it programmatically in item object. When i create those items to populate the wrap panel, i add a reference to created ContentPresenter that represents the item itself and the root parent, which in this case is a UserControl.

Referenced ContentPresenter is needed to animate the item.
Referenced root parent UserControl is needed to get the current location of the item in the user control.

Now the animations look like this:

[webm 3](http://webmshare.com/play/GyPQw)
[webm 4](http://webmshare.com/play/YXbM5)

I added this method in CountryItem:

```
    private void AnimateToCenter ( )
    {

        var sbTranslate = new Storyboard();
        var daTranslateX = new DoubleAnimation();
        var daTranslateY = new DoubleAnimation();
        var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        daTranslateX.Duration = duration;
        daTranslateY.Duration = duration;
        sbTranslate.Duration = duration;

        var exponentialEase = new ExponentialEase();
        exponentialEase.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut;
        exponentialEase.Exponent = 16;

        daTranslateX.EasingFunction = exponentialEase;
        daTranslateY.EasingFunction = exponentialEase;

        sbTranslate.Children.Add(daTranslateX);
        sbTranslate.Children.Add(daTranslateY);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(daTranslateX, this.This);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(daTranslateY, this.This);

        this.This.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daTranslateX, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daTranslateY, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"));

        //get the current point of the selected item
        var currentPoint = this.This.TranslatePoint(new Point(), this.Parent);

        //get actual width and height of the parent so we can calculate to which position to calculate
        var parentWidth = (this.Parent as UserControl).ActualWidth;
        var parentHeight = (this.Parent as UserControl).ActualHeight;

        //get actual width and height of the item itself to center the item correctly
        //this is needed because the X and Y coordinates of the item are top and left
        var thisWidth = (this.This as ContentPresenter).ActualWidth;
        var thisHeight = (this.This as ContentPresenter).ActualHeight;

        //animate the item to the center of the screen
        daTranslateX.To = (parentWidth / 2) - currentPoint.X - (thisWidth / 2);
        daTranslateY.To = (parentHeight / 2) - currentPoint.Y - (thisHeight / 2);

        sbTranslate.Begin();
    }
```

and it's called here:

```
        private void IsInEditModeToggleMethod ( )
        {
            this.IsEllipseVisible = true;
            var countryViewModel = ViewModelFinder.FindOne<CountryViewModel>();
            countryViewModel.Countries.Where(x=>x.Id != this.Id).ToList().ForEach(ci => ci.IsVisible = false);
            this.IsInEditMode = !this.IsInEditMode;
            this.AnimateToCenter();
        }
```

Comment: The links are dead :(