# How to get the position of a control in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to get the position of a control relative to its parent, or just any kind of position, doesn't really matter. But I want to do this only in XAML without any code behind. I have a grid 5x3, and the button is located in 3rd row and 2nd column. So, basically I would like to get the width of first two rows of the grid, and the width of the first column of the gird.

I want to know the position of the button in pixels, because I want to do translation animation like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="500" To="0" Duration="0:0:2">
```

but instead of using hardcoded value of 500, I want it to be anything that corresponds to the button's horisontal position in pixels

Comment: I use MVVM and tend not to write any code behind. I know that MVVM is not about eliminating the code behind completely, but so far in my application I didn't have to write any code behind, and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: I mean why do you want to know position of previous Control in Visual Tree?

Comment: I want to know the position of the button in pixels, because I want to do translation animation like this: <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="500" To="0" Duration="0:0:2"> but instead of using hardcoded value of 500, I want it to be anything that corresponds to the button's horisontal position in pixels.

Comment: put the reason to your question. It will help to you to get answer faster

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense, as the (animated) TranslateTransform is relative to the Button, not to the Button's Parent. Instead of dealing with positions in XAML, you better explain the desired behaviour of your UI (i.e. how the Button shall actually move), so that we can provide a suitable solution.

Comment: Ok, I simply want the button to move from right to left, so I need starting point and ending point. The starting point is going to be the button's position relative to 'something' (in pixels) and this is what I want to get (IN XAML ONLY). The reason why I mentioned the parent control is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060685/xaml-get-user-control-position-relative-to-whole-window-as-binding-property

Comment: When the TranslateTransform is assigned to the Button's RenderTransform, you would animate from `0` to some negative value (i.e. to the left).

Comment: That's impossible to do with XAML because From and To properties require compile time constants. Storyboard is freezed when you start the application because the animations need to be thread safe, and dynamic properties don't allow that. I had a similar problem and had to do it in the ViewModel take a look: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826711/c-sharp-set-translatetransform-x-and-y-property-relative-to-mainwindow)

Comment: Thanks but it seems little too complicated for me right now. I am just thinking of quick dirty solution by inserting some dummy transparent rectangles in the View and position them in right place, and then just use their 'width' attached properties as binding parameters for 'from' and 'to'.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic "From and To properties require compile time constants" This is not true, since these are dependency properties and can get their values from Bindings (or other sources). I can image that a solution with a Binding and an appropriate binding converter might be suitable here.

Comment: @Clemens If he's using a style or a datatemplate/controltemplate those properties are not bindable

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic Is he? I guess not. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the XAML below might work for you. It is inspired by your idea of a transparent dummy Rectangle that fills the columns left of the Button.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle x:Name="dummy" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Click">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].X"
                            To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dummy}"
                            Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

---

Instead of declaring the RenderTransform as shown above you may perhaps better use a binding converter to invert the value of the dummy Rectangle's `ActualWidth` property.

Comment: can you please give me some hint for that converter?

Comment: Take a look at the online documentation of the `Binding.Converter` property. Your implementation would just `return -(double)value;` from its Convert method.